# Is there a pragma directive for include directories?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, pragma

As the title says: Is there a pragma directive for include directories using VS20** C++? I think about something like:

```
#pragma comment(include, "..\externals\blah\includes\")
```

So that I can use includes in this style, and blah.h also can use this style inside?

```
#include <blah.h>
```

I know that I can set include directories in my project settings, but I am asking for a preprocessor directive, because else i would have to set it for every compiler profile.

Regards Nem

Comment: You are aware you can multiselect profiles and then set the include folder?

Comment: Yep, but at least by adding one single profile I have to set it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to do this.  [include_alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbeh5h91.aspx) is only useful on a file-by-file basis.

Comment: Yes but in this way i also could modify the header files of every external project.

Answer (score 10):

you can create a txt file (ex. IncludeDirs.txt). Inside that file you can add the include folders:

```
/I "."
/I ".."
/I ".\OtherFolder"
```

then in the *properties->configuration properties->C/C++-> Command line*
add the following string:

```
@includedirs.txt
```

You can create a different file for each profile (Debug, Release, etc.)

Comment: Nice - only downside is it being buried in the project settings in a 'non-standard' location, but if it only needs to be done once, it might make things a lot easier..

Comment: Great idea! Linux equivalent (using clang by happenstance): `clang++ $(cat CompilerOptions.txt) ...`

Answer (score 2):

You may want to create a **.props** file that contains a selected set of predefined Visual Studio project properties (any of those that you normally see in Project Properties sections like C/C++, Linker etc).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
    <PropertyGroup>
        <IncludePath>C:\ExampleDir\Include;$(IncludePath)</IncludePath>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

You can move blocks of existing properties from your **.vcxproj** file(s).
It may also contain per **Configuration** conditions for properties (this is also something you can learn from insides of a .vcxproj file that is an XML text file).

*Important*:
The .props file needs to be referenced from the Property Manager tab
 [View] - [Property Manager] menu - select [Add Existing Property Sheet...]
   while focusing a specific build configuration or the whole project.

These **.props** property files are well reusable between different projects.
Combined with Environment Variable values (e.g. use $(MySdkPath) instead of a specific "C:\MySdk") this approach provides a good and universal solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any.

A while ago I solved this problem by making "all" and "all.cpp" files in every directory to include each header and source file in it. It needs some manual work to create and maintain but I believe it is worth it. This way I can just write something like `#include <Frigo/Math/all>`. It might be even possible to create a script that updates them automatically.

Comment: Are you familiar with precompiled headers?

Comment: It was a long time ago since I bothered with C++. But yeah I am familiar with precompiled headers, unfortunately they are not really compatible with templates.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a "master folder" to your project properties and then put the right folder in the include directive, for example:

folder **"includes"** with subfolders **"Unicode"/"ASCII"**, both with a header-file named "String.h" (you shouldn't use the same name)

in code use:

```
#ifdef UNICODE // or your preprocessor flag
#  include <Unicode/string.h>
#else 
#  include <ASCII/string.h>
#endif
```

you also can use DEBUG or any keyword, as long as you specify it in `Project-Settings --> C/C++ --> Preprocessor --> Preprocessor defintions`

Comment: Sorry, but I know that. I'm not sure whether you understand my question correctly. If you would have read my post, you would know that this is not what i intended with my question.

Answer (score 1):

I am coming too late, but I tried

```
#define path_include <C:/foo_folder/##a>
```

and then

```
#include path_include(blah.h)

#include path_include(bluh.h)
```

It works.

Comment: I think the asker wants to modify the include path with a pragma. I don't think this answers their question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a clever idea, but it would be imperative to be able to preserve existing `#include`s without modifying them