# Visual Studio 2019: Pass include paths between chain-referenced projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

Let's suppose we have an existing Visual Studio 2019 solution that can't be generated from scratch with another tool, e.g. CMake.

The solution contains three projects: A, B and C, each containing only one file, this is a minimal example:

```
/// Project A, A.hpp
// content irrelevant

/// Project B, B.hpp
#include <A.hpp>  // B's public interface includes A's header

/// Project C.cpp
#include <B.hpp>  // C requires B's header, which includes A's header, to compile
```

Being used to CMake's "target-based" approach, I naively thought that I could handle things if:

- B references A,
- C references B

In this case however, C only consumes B's include paths, but it does not consume A's include paths. The C therefore does not compile.

The "workaround" which just "makes it work" is obvious: add A's include paths to C and it will compile. But we know that this scales horribly when number of project grows:

```
> /// Project C2, C2.cpp 
> #include <B.hpp>  // requires B interface to compile

> /// Project C3, C3.cpp 
> #include <B.hpp>  // requires B interface to compile

> /// Project C4, C5, ... and on and on
```

Instead of having to having to specify the needs of B's interface across many projects, I am seeking what CMake offers: define the requirements (in my case: include paths) of B in B project itself and that's it.

My question is: how to achieve this entirely **from within the Visual Studio 2019 IDE**?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAMws.png]

Comment: Do you want a CMake solution or a pure VS solution? As far as I understood you, you don't want CMake - so what has it to do with CMake at all?

Comment: In addition linking seems to be already configured (Reference nodes in solution explorer). So basically you want to adjust the include paths for your projects, right?

Comment: @Bernd Thank you for pointing that out, I am indeed looking for pure VS solution. I removed the cmake tag now. As for other question, yes - include paths.

Comment: I don't believe VS has any such option. Besides, it is not correct to include all A's includes. As in general A might have some includes totally unnecessary includes for B. I manage it rather simply. I never write `#include "B.hpp"` but rather `#include "B/B.hpp"` so projects need to include but the folder all projects are located in. Or if you have multiple folders your projects are located in, you could even write it like `#include "SolName/B/B.hpp"` so the whole include is but a single folder for the entire solution (besides the third party includes...)

Comment: The usual 100% UI way is to define the #include the way you want, ie: "a\a.hpp" or "a.hpp", etc.., and then "play" with referencing projects properties "Configuration Properties" / "VC++ Directories" / "Include Directories" and add the relative path, ie: ".." or "..\a" or anything else. This way you never change the source code but can create an infinite variation of projects. Otherwise you can use MSBuild's .csproj to do more powerful stuff.

Comment: Select *all* projects in the Solution Explorer window (Shift+Click makes it easy).  Project > Properties, note the comboboxes at the top of the dialog.  Select "All Configurations" and "All Platforms".

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the include path manully with right project click, properties, "C++ directories"
[image]

This works but performs not really well / is not that nice. You could configure it via MSBuild e.g. with a shared props file, too. But I do not like that approach either.

In my eyes the best option to do this, not just for multiple parts (exe, dlls... ) - but for cross-compiliation, too - is the usage a shared library / project with shared elements.

This allows you to put all interface files right there. I go even a step further - my projects contain no code - it is stored completely in shared projects.
With this setup you can create for example a Windows Project which uses MSVC and a Linux version compiled with GCC using the same code base. Or create a static or dynamic library - nothing is fixed.

To use code from a shared project you can add it simply as reference (as you did with your other projects) - quite easy.
If you need further help - please ask.

Here you can find a sample on github: https://github.com/bernd5/Stackoverflow-VS-Sample

For help some picture (my VS is in German - but I hope you can work with it):

[image: Create Shared Project]
[image: Project-Explorer]

---

If you dislike the shared library approach you can find an alternative approach without ".." here:
First you need to adjust the include-directories property for each project to:
[image: with SolutionDir]
(Added MSBuild-Variable `SolutionDir`)

Then you can simply write:

```
#include "A/A.h"
```

Comment: BTW.: if you need 3rd party libraries like boost or openCV I would recommend to you vcpkg - it has a nice MSBuild integration

Comment: Do you still miss something? Please leave a comment...

Answer (score 0):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/adding-references-in-visual-cpp-projects?view=msvc-160#consuming-static-libraries it seems that they recommend accessing the headers using:

```
#include "../A/A.hpp"
```

Which just exploits the solution structure and continues to work.

I just tested this and it does work...
I put the example at https://github.com/kyotov/ABC

Comment: It works usually - but in my eyes the usage of ".." is a bad design and error-prone. Here you can find a thread with same topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120330/include-parent-directorys-file

Comment: It would be better to add the solution root path to the include-path-set as described by  ALX23z

Comment: @Bernd Unless you have C++/20 and modules, this is the correct answer. I can agree that’s a bad design, but that bad design is from 1972 when C was introduced.

Comment: Of course #include is very old mechanism - simple and hard to do correctly (mostly: include as less as possible).
But that's not the point here - I wanted to say that ".." is bad style.
Okay, in Visual studio it is not that bad because you usually do not create sub-folders in projects just virtual ones called "filter" but in general it should be avoided.

Comment: Completely agree, it is just hard to avoid. One option (which is a bit better, but not ideal, and you mentioned it already) is to include the root of the solution to the include paths. This way you can skip the ".." but you will still need to be doing `#include <project>/<path>/<file>`. A good practice is to create a special directory in the project with public headers -- i.e. headers that you intend to be used by the customers of the project. Then make sure you only include from there... e.g. `#include "A/api/header.h"`

Answer (score 0):

As some commented, the easiest way to fix that may be to add an upper level folder as include path and then include files relatively from here.

If your code is structured like that:

```
your_code/
    A/
        a.hpp
        a.cpp
    B/
        b.hpp
        b.cpp
    C/
        c.hpp
        c.cpp
```

Then, instead of adding `your_code/A` in `B`'s include path and `your_code/B` in `C`'s, add `your_code` to eveyone's and then include `A/a.hpp` from `B` and `B/b.hpp` from `C`. I think this approach is cleaner than using `..` in your includes as proposed by Kamen.

The code can be organized differently (have `inc`/`src` folders to isolate headers/implementations, repeat library name under `inc` folder so that people having `any_lib`'s `inc` in their library path would include `any_lib/...hpp` to avoid conflicts in header files lookup...), but in the end, the approach remains the same, try to have `B` lookup for `A`'s include relatively from a place also known by `C` so that it finds it too.

Anyway, the good solution (long term) may be to use `CMake` in the end (or any build system) handling that correctly for you, but that is apparently not an option right now.

---

Edit: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17819198/3336423) shows how to add a bunch of includes to a projet. You may also use that, have a `IncludeDirsForB.txt` with everything needed by `B` path and add `@IncludeDirsForB.txt` to the command line of every project using `B`...?