# Set VC++ Directories for all projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have one Visual Studio Solution with multiple projects in it. Anytime I need to add new headers/libs to the project i need to go to properties of each project in VC++ Directories and set the path for include and lib.

Is there any easier way to do this? To modify the solution with proper path and all the projects in it inherit that?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps try the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069456/is-there-a-pragma-directive-for-include-directories) you can create a single text file, which you include using @includedirs.txt

Comment: [Share or reuse Visual Studio project settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations)

Comment: Oh I didnt know we can include a text file like that! that will definitely help. No sure how to mark that comment as answer for my question.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a single text file such as `includes.txt`, with contents in this format:

```
/I "folder1"
/I "folder2"
```

Then include the file in each project by setting `Properties`->`configuration properties`->`C/C++`->`Command Line` in the `Additional Options` section you add:

```
@includes.txt
```